# Selecting a REST server using Geolocation

Tags: javascript, rest, geolocation, single-page-application

Suppose a single page application that consumes rest services is loaded in Singapore and there are two possible locations hosting the REST / edge services that the application consumes, one in New York and one in Singapore.  Anyone know of a javascript framework that would allow the app to select the closest data center (In this case it would be Singapore)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Onload of application get data centers lat lon in http rest call.
2. Get your current device lat lon position by Cordova geolocation or any other plugin
3. Use this algorithm to calculate distance in your device itself between all the list of data centers and device current location then shortlist the distance and pick shortest

   ```
   function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) { 
        var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km 
        var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1); // deg2rad below 
        var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
        var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
        var d = R * c; // Distance in km 
      return d; 
   } 

   function deg2rad(deg) {
       return deg * (Math.PI/180) 
   }
   ```

Comment: I love this answer - if my kids ever ask me what the trigonometry stuff is for - this is the perfect example.